# What is a word for someone who does things to forget about painful things?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example, if someone lost a family member and decides that instead of crying they're gonna rub off their pain by playing basketball for 8 hours of their day.

Comment: *The Five Stages of Grief
An Examination of the Kubler-Ross Model* https://www.psycom.net/stages-of-grief

Comment: Sounds like *self-soothing*?

Comment: You can use the word "stoic".

Comment: I don't know if there's a word for the person, but the action is called "drowning your sorrows"

Comment: I suggest there is no such word. Either way, might it help to distinguish between doing things to ignore pain, or to help deal with it?

Comment: Someone who does it occasionally, or more often than usual, or all the time? It seems pretty common behaviour that almost everyone does sometimes, so I guess *human*.

Answer (score 1):

**escapist**
/ɪˈskeɪpɪst/

noun
*a person who seeks distraction and relief from unpleasant realities, especially in the form of entertainment or fantasy.*

"the perfect escapist's paradise, almost as remote as a desert island"

adjective
*providing or seeking distraction and relief from unpleasant realities, especially in the form of entertainment or fantasy.*

"I was ready for a good escapist read"

Comment: You should include the source of this definition.